# Intent Filters and android:pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent, path, intentfilter

In my application, I want to handle links that use the following pattern:

`scheme://host/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/article`

I got it to work temporarily, by using the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="www.laprensa.com.ni" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, as you may imagine that opens any link that starts with `scheme://host`, and I want to make sure I only pick up on those that have the above stated pattern, where the page is 4 folders inside the host.

Another little problem is that the folder names are never the same, and therefore I cannot simply use `android:path`. It's also worth noting that the `android:pathPrefix` is not the same, as the first three folder are date related.

For instance, the urls are strucutred something like this:

`scheme://host/year/month/day/articleType/article`

I've been reading the docs and questions on how to use `android:pathPattern` but I really don't understand what I'm supposed to type in.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Upon suggestion, I tried:

`android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*"`

Where each '.*' represented a folder but that seems to still pick up the other URLs that are not articles. For example, here are two different urls:

Url I want to handle:

```
http://www.laprensa.com.ni/2013/05/10/vida/145996-lionel-richie-defiende-a
```

Url I don't want to handle

```
http://www.laprensa.com.ni/2013/05/10/vida/
```

I guess the problem here is that they both have the same amount of levels, the only difference is that one actually has something after that last `'/'`, any other ideas I can try? I did try adding one more `'/.*'` but that stopped working completely and the app stopped handling any links period :(

Comment: Try using <data android:pathPattern="*/*/*/*">

Comment: daniel_c05 How did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 32):

You're close, but missing the final part. This should work for you:

`android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/..*"`

This will match any paths with four repeating `/[anything]` as well as enforce that you must have *something* after the final `/`.

Just as you asked:

> Url I want to handle:
>
> `http://www.laprensa.com.ni/2013/05/10/vida/145996-lionel-richie-defiende-a`
>
> Url I don't want to handle
>
> `http://www.laprensa.com.ni/2013/05/10/vida/`

#### Explanation

The `.` enforces a pattern of "one of any character".
The `.*` enforces "any number (or none!) of any character".

Combining these two, `..*` enforces "any number of any characters, but at least one must be provided"

Comment: Can you please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809067/andoid-pathpattern-regex-issue

Comment: If i was looking at an url like `https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/exampleuser-225/0123456` and the id I wanted to fetch was `0123456`, would it then be possible to use `android:pathPattern="/users/..*/..*"` ?

Answer (score 6):

You should add exactly the `android:pathPattern` attribute to configuration you defined.
As reported in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path), `android:pathPattern` can contain following wildcards for building simplified regular expressions:

- An asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the immediately preceding character.
- A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.

In your case:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="www.laprensa.com.ni"
      android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*" />
```

Where each .* represent a folder name.

Comment: Somehow I thought it worked, but it didn't, I updated the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, wildcards used for `android:pathPattern` are a very reduced subset of common regular expressions. Basing on documentation it's not possible to handle your need only by using  `android:pathPattern`. Considering you're trying to access documents, you can try to exploit the additional attribute `android:mimeType`. There you can use value `text/*` or for example `text/html`.

Comment: @thetonrifles can you please  review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809067/andoid-pathpattern-regex-issue