# Android pathPattern Regex issue

Tags: android, android-intent, glob, intentfilter

I am facing a problem related to Android Intent-Filters esp. in data-element with a path pattern
Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

I need to match a pattern for valid URLs like

> **anything**-to-**anything**-trains
>
> **fromString**-to-**toString**-trains

Below mentioned pattern is working almost perfectly

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*to.*trains" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*to.*trains/" />
```

However, this pattern is failing when from or to contain keyword 't'

e.g.

1. t-to-a-trains
2. a-to-t-trains
3. a-to-ata-trains
4. ata-to-aa-trains

For the given problem, anything including the keyword 't' should be matched with using the path pattern. Can you please suggest to me how to write a proper pattern for such a situation? I am a beginner in creating path patterns (regex or wildcard or pattern glob) but the pattern that I used in `android:pathPattern` work in regex testing sites but not with path pattern.

Additionally, Can we support regex with a **special symbol like hyphen '-'**?

I see symbol # doesn't work due to the Pattern matcher requirement.

---

According to [PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher#PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB), the path pattern doesn't work how it is documented as there is no need to escape the Asterix.

Doc:

> Because '' is used as an escape character when the string is read
> from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern), you will need to
> double-escape: For example, a literal '*' would be written as "\*"
> and a literal '' would be written as "\\". This is basically the
> same as what you would need to write if constructing the string in
> Java code.

---

Note: This question is not related to working of regex or not. Pattern/Regex working fine on regex tester site doesn't mean it will work on Android Platform as Andriod Intent filters have some limitation in parsing. It has only two wildcards as per the document.

---

To test the deeplink, please use following adb command:

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "deep link"
> [package name (optional)]

Example:

```
 adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.website.com/a-to-a-trains" com.website.sample.package
```

Comment: No, it works, see https://regex101.com/r/fNg50s/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yup, Regex is working but may be due to Android Filter limitation this is excluding the case where fromString and toString contain t character. Need someone may be from Android background to answer this.

Comment: Does this fail when there's a `t` anywhere, or only at the end, e.g. does `ted-to-tom-trains` work?

Comment: Yes if t comes anywhere. Let me add this invalid sample usecase  in the question

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB` doc, not much you can do.

> In this syntax, you can use the '*' character to match against zero or more occurrences of the character immediately before. If the character before it is '.' it will match any character. The character '' can be used as an escape. This essentially provides only the '*' wildcard part of a normal regexp

So this should work.

`.*-to-.*-trains`

Comment: Unfortunately, This pattern is behaving the same as the one I have mentioned.

Comment: Well in that case your only option is to use multiple wildcards like so ``<data android:pathPattern=".*to.*trains" />``, ``<data android:pathPattern=".*.*to.*.*trains" />``, ``<data android:pathPattern=".*.*.*to.*.*.*trains" />`` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special characters using **\ (backslash)**.

i.e.

```
\- or \.
```

And for your solution, this may work,

```
[A-Za-z0-9].*\-.[A-Za-z0-9].*
```

Comment: Looks like regex is not supported in path pattern in the Android Intent filter.