# Opening a file from implicit intent in a Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.forms

My xamarin.forms app works with sqlite3 files which have the extension `.rde`, and I want people to be able to open `.rde` files from the files app, downloaded from the browser etc., with an implicit intent.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://codemilltech.com/sending-files-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-2-android/) and modified the intent to match my extension:

```cs
namespace myapp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "myapp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionEdit }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataPathPattern = ".*\\.rde", DataSchemes = new[] { "file", "content" }, DataHost = "*", DataMimeType = "*/*")]
    //...
}
```

This doesn't appear to be sufficient. When I install this app on my device and try to open a downloaded .rde file, the files app shows an alert "Search the Play Store? You don't have any apps that can open this type of file." What do I need to change to register this intent with the `.rde` file type, or how can I diagnose why Android doesn't match my intent in this case?

Comment: Maybe you need Intent.ActionView?

Comment: Thank you @blackapps, unfortunately adding that action didn't change the outcome.

Comment: `DataMimeType = "*/*"` DataMimeType = "*/rde" ?

Comment: DataPathPattern = ".*\\.rde" Mostly you need more of them to allow for files in sub-sub-subdirectories and so.

Comment: @blackapps I don't understand why your other proposed changes would help. I don't think there _is_ any mime type matching `*/rde`, and I don't see how the regex `.*\\.rde` _doesn't_ already match the path separator.

Comment: I dont know that. But have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490907/intent-filters-and-androidpathpattern/16491465 And sorry i cannot find the other intent filters i saw before and have in mind.

Comment: Great, thanks I'll check out the other question

Comment: That question is about how to match paths of a particular depth. I don't have that problem; I have the problem that my intent is not being triggered despite matching the path regex.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm not permitted to access those intents, and instead should be using [the storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files). [This sample](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/blob/main/ActionOpenDocument/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/actionopendocument/MainActivity.kt) shows how it's done in Kotlin, and I'm using the dependency service in Xamarin.Forms to invoke a C# rewrite of that.